# angularJS bind a variable in a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bind

I have a dropdown menu :

```
<select ng-model="dropdown" ng-options="item.serverID as item.serverName for item in choiceServers"></select>
```

And the different items of the dropdown menu are in an array : choiceServers.
This array changes during the time, adding new items.

The problem is that I have always the same initial items when I use my dropdown menu, the variable choiceServers is not updated in my html file.

I have tried to use double-curly and so on, but I didn't figure out how to do this. I would need to constantly update the variable choiceServers, so that it has the same items than in the jsfile where I modify it.

Thank you for your help !

EDIT :

here is where choiceServers is changed :

```
//Drop-down menu
$scope.choiceServers = [ //Static list for the moment 
    {serverID: 1, serverName : 'Server 1'},
    {serverID: 2, serverName : 'Server 2'},
    {serverID: 3, serverName : 'Server 3'},
    {serverID: 4, serverName : 'Server 4'},
]; 

socket.on('newServer', function(newServer){ //New Agent/server
    $scope.choiceServers.push(newServer); //We add his PID in the list
});

$scope.dropdown = 1; // In order to avoid a blank as a first option
```

And here is the event emit :

```
//Dropdown menu 
    var lastID = 5; // doesn't matter for the moment
    var newServer = {serverID : lastID , serverName : PID };
    socket.broadcast.emit('newServer', newServer);
```

The server sends me an object {serverID, serverName}, and I push it.
I have checked and the push function is working, choiceServer has more and more items (every time the event is called)

EDIT 2 :

Ok I finally found. I had to add $scope.$apply() after the update of choiceServers

Comment: How are you changing the array `choiceServers`. Show us that code

Comment: Are you sure the array changes by time? how? show the code that is changing your array.

Comment: Can you add Script code You are using.. otherwise nobody can give a proper answer without seeing script file

Comment: I have added the code, sorry :)

Comment: try adding a $scope.$apply() after your choiceServers.push line

Comment: Yes it was excactly the problem, thanks :) !

Comment: No problem! $scope.$apply() is useful whenever you modify a controller's data from outside the normal angular execution, like if you used a setTimeout instead of angular's $timeout

Answer (score 0):

Change like this :

```
<select ng-model="item.serverName" ng-options="item.serverID as item.serverName for item in choiceServers"></select>
```

If it's also not working, 
When you try to bind the data using script file $scope. choiceServers is not updated. Therefore, it gives same data again and again.

or

Use $scope.$root instead of $scope

Comment: yes, that's the problem, but do you know how to display the new data

Comment: Well I meant to have the new items added in my dropdown menu

Comment: $scope.$root instead of $scope